# Difficulty with try and catch statements?

Tags: c#

How in the world do I set a try and catch to stop the user from inputting more than one decimal. Is it a try and catch? Or what exactly do i want to do here?
Very new to windows form applications....

Also somewthing to note... when I click the calculations the numbers dissapear.. it doesn't continuously stay there. I thought that was odd. Would anyone know why? For example if I hit 6 + 6 it shows "6" and then another "6" and then 12, not a display of 6 + 6 = 12.
I dont understand that either

EDIT: 
Here is an updated code. I have everything EXCEpt I still don't understand how to continuously have the code written. Any suggestions welcomed as I am stuck...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    char c;
    double num1;
    double num2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 0;
    }
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 1;
    }
    private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 2;
    }
    private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 3;
    }
    private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 4;
    }
    private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 5;
    }
    private void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 6;
    }
    private void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 7;
    }
    private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 8;
    }
    private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 9;
    }
    private void btnDecimal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!txtBox.Text.Contains("."))
            txtBox.Text += ".";
    }
    private void btnAddition_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c = '+';
        num1 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        txtBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    private void btnSubtraction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c = '-';
        num1 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        txtBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    private void btnMultiplication_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c = '*';
        num1 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        txtBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    private void btnDivision_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c = '/';
        num1 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        txtBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Clear();
    }
    private void btnEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num2 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        double result;
        switch (c)
        {
            case '+':
                result = num1 + num2;
                txtBox.Text = result.ToString();
                break;
            case '-':
                result = num1 - num2;
                txtBox.Text = result.ToString();
                break;
            case '/':
                 if (num2!= 0) 
                {
                    result = num1 / num2;
                    txtBox.Text = result.ToString();
                } 
                else 
                {
                    txtBox.Text = "You can't divide by zero... sign up for Math 100 please =)";
                } 
                break; 
            case '*':
                result = num1 * num2;
                txtBox.Text = result.ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Just a tip. [switch statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) should be preferred over statements like `if (c==1) else if (c==2) etc.`

Comment: Why is this? Does it run faster with case/switch or..? Im still learning c# basics it seems.

Comment: A `switch case` statement is mainly more readable than `else if`s and on large scales it's even more efficient

Comment: You are learning windows forms. Good. One of the things you should get used to very early, because they will be *very* important down the line is to give your controls (and forms) better names. `button1` adds a `"1"`, `button2` adds a `"2"`, while not that good of names, at least the make some sense. But why does `button5` add a `"3"`? (because it was the sixth button, starting with zero, you added to the form and just happen to move it to the position where adding `"3"` made sense.) Name the control for what they do, for example `append3` or `btnAppend3`.

Comment: So say the user inputs more than one decimal number, there isn't a way to "stop" the user from successfully accomplishing that without an alternative? such as if they input more than one decimal is automatically makes it one decimal, or if they input more than one decimal it sends a messagebox warning that the operation cannot work.

Comment: @Corak Yea I know I need to name the buttons correctly. I should have done that earlier because it gets confusing!

Comment: With a `switch` statement, the execution can jump right into the right case. With `if ... else if ... else if ...` in worst case, every condition needs to be checked to know that the last `else` should be executed.

Comment: To control, what (button) input is legal at any time, you can play around with the [Enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled.aspx) property of the controls.

Comment: It is not showing 6 + 6 = 12 because on operator you are going to empty text box, For example in last line of method btnAddition_Click your wrote txtBox.Text = string.Empty; 
You have to change this logic to achieve 6+6=12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all you don't need a try catch statement. try catch statement are meant for exception handling.

after clearing that, what you want is a single method to add the current input to a number you keep in memory and showing it on the screen. i won't show you code because you have a lot to change, but basically you should look at a [calculator example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Simple-Calculator-d1d8cf4c)

Comment: I have figured out how to keep it from allowing more than one decimal. I still do not understand how to store it in memory and display it continuously. Could you may be a little more specific?

Comment: case "+":
                    result = num1 + num2;
                    textBox1.Text = num1 + c + num2 + " = " + result.ToString();
                    break;

Comment: That is the closest of what I have gotten, but it does not continuously show it. So a user is still able to see what their input was, but not "continuously"...

Comment: @Azzamean when you say "So a user is still able to see what their input was, but not "continuously"" what do you mean? do you mean the user need to see their entire equation? like "5 + 4 - 2 * 5" and so on?

Comment: exactly. That is my goal. I believe it is with parsing but I do not know where or when I am making a casting mistake.

Comment: It seems even if I parse the result it crashes, because maybe the "+" is not parsed?

Answer (score 2):

yes You dont need Try catch Block its for exception handling and u have to change your code at so may b you try this it helps you............

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Drawing; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Windows.Forms; 

namespace SimpleCalculator 
{ 
    public partial class frmCalculator : Form 
    { 
        string operand1 = string.Empty; 
        string operand2 = string.Empty; 
        string result; 
        char operation; 

        public frmCalculator() 
        { 
            InitializeComponent(); 
        } 

        private void frmCalculator_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            btnOne.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click); 
            btnTwo.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click); 
            btnThree.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click); 
            btnFour.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click); 
            btnFive.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click); 
            btnSix.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click); 
            btnSeven.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click); 
            btnEight.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click); 
            btnNine.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click); 
            btnZero.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click); 
            btnDot.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click); 
        } 

        void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            try 
            { 
                Button btn = sender as Button; 

                switch (btn.Name) 
                { 
                    case "btnOne": 
                        txtInput.Text += "1"; 
                        break; 
                    case "btnTwo": 
                        txtInput.Text += "2"; 
                        break; 
                    case "btnThree": 
                        txtInput.Text += "3"; 
                        break; 
                    case "btnFour": 
                        txtInput.Text += "4"; 
                        break; 
                    case "btnFive": 
                        txtInput.Text += "5"; 
                        break; 
                    case "btnSix": 
                        txtInput.Text += "6"; 
                        break; 
                    case "btnSeven": 
                        txtInput.Text += "7"; 
                        break; 
                    case "btnEight": 
                        txtInput.Text += "8"; 
                        break; 
                    case "btnNine": 
                        txtInput.Text += "9"; 
                        break; 
                    case "btnZero": 
                        txtInput.Text += "0"; 
                        break; 
                    case "btnDot": 
                        if(!txtInput.Text.Contains(".")) 
                            txtInput.Text += "."; 
                        break; 

                } 
            } 
            catch(Exception ex) 
            { 
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry for the inconvenience, Unexpected error occured. Details: " + 
                    ex.Message); 
            } 
        } 

        private void txtInput_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) 
        { 
            switch (e.KeyChar) 
            { 
                case '1': 
                case '2': 
                case '3': 
                case '4': 
                case '5': 
                case '6': 
                case '7': 
                case '8': 
                case '9': 
                case '0': 
                //case '+': 
                //case '-': 
                //case '*': 
                //case '/': 
                //case '.': 
                    break; 
                default: 
                    e.Handled = true; 
                    MessageBox.Show("Only numbers, +, -, ., *, / are allowed"); 
                    break; 
            }            
        } 

        private void txtInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 

        } 

        private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            operand1 = txtInput.Text; 
            operation = '+'; 
            txtInput.Text = string.Empty; 
        } 

        private void btnMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            operand1 = txtInput.Text; 
            operation = '-'; 
            txtInput.Text = string.Empty; 
        } 

        private void btnMulitply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            operand1 = txtInput.Text; 
            operation = '*'; 
            txtInput.Text = string.Empty; 
        } 

        private void btnDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            operand1 = txtInput.Text; 
            operation = '/'; 
            txtInput.Text = string.Empty; 
        } 

        private void btnEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            operand2 = txtInput.Text; 

            double opr1, opr2; 
            double.TryParse(operand1, out opr1); 
            double.TryParse(operand2, out opr2); 

            switch (operation) 
            { 
                case '+': 
                    result = (opr1 + opr2).ToString(); 
                    break; 

                case '-': 
                    result = (opr1 - opr2).ToString(); 
                    break; 

                case '*': 
                    result = (opr1 * opr2).ToString(); 
                    break; 

                case '/': 
                    if (opr2 != 0) 
                    { 
                        result = (opr1 / opr2).ToString(); 
                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                        MessageBox.Show("Can't divide by zero"); 
                    } 
                    break; 
            } 

            txtInput.Text = result.ToString(); 
        } 

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            txtInput.Text = string.Empty; 
            operand1 = string.Empty; 
            operand2 = string.Empty; 
        } 

        private void btnSqrRoot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            double opr1; 
            if (double.TryParse(txtInput.Text, out opr1)) 
            { 
                txtInput.Text = (Math.Sqrt(opr1)).ToString(); 
            } 
        } 

        private void btnByTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            double opr1; 
            if (double.TryParse(txtInput.Text, out opr1)) 
            { 
                txtInput.Text = (opr1 / 2).ToString(); 
            } 
        } 

        private void btnByFour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            double opr1; 
            if (double.TryParse(txtInput.Text, out opr1)) 
            { 
                txtInput.Text = (opr1 / 4).ToString(); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: you should put the operation as an enum and all the operand buttons as you did with the numbers. i know it's not your code, but a fix to the  Azzamean code, but you should at least mention it